# left join query of mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreign-keys

I'm working on a project where I have two tables 1 is the Users table and another one in the Department table. here I have given a foreign key connection to the department table to the user's table and checked that is working fine. (getting data of particular foreign key). now my requirement is in a single table I want to display all users along with that the foreign key value also. here.

```
require_once "database.php";

$result = "SELECT * FROM Users";
// , Department WHERE Department.Department_ID = Users.Dpt_id
$output = mysqli_query($conn, $result);


<?php
          while ($single = $output->fetch_assoc()):?>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $single['firstname']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $single['lastname']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $single['email']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $single['phnumber']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $single['provider']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $single['location']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $single['Dpt_id']; ?>
            


          </td>
          <td><?php if ($single['Dadmin'] == 1){
                echo '<p>Department admin</p>';
            }
            elseif($single['Superuser'] == 1){
              echo '<p>SUPER</p>';
            }
            else{
              echo '<p>USER</p>';
            }

            ?></td>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

tried code:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM Users, Department WHERE 
Department.Department_ID = Users.Dpt_id";
$output = mysqli_query($conn, $result);
```

so here is my code. please help me to get the value from the foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this result but i don't know your column name:

```
SELECT u.*, d.department_name
FROM USERS u
LEFT JOIN Department d 
ON u.dpt_id = d.department_id
```

Comment: your ans is correct but i'm sorry i don't have a reputation to upvote you. but I'm heartily thank you for your answer it solved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT u.*, d.department_id 
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN Department d 
ON u.dpt_id = d.department_id
```

Comment: it's getting only the value which is having Dpt_id in Users table. what i need is the User may have r not have Department still he should be shown in table.

Comment: Instead of INNER JOIN set LEFT JOIN

Comment: and i dont need inner join here. coz it only returns the matching rows. i need to print all users along with that i need to print department name from another table

Comment: Left join would get all users that dont and that have join with department. But I think that you have changed your question a little bit: "now my requirement is in a single table i want to display all users along with that the foreign key value also" if you want to print something along with the foreign key, it means that they have join... SO if  you want to get all users that dont have matching row, that have matching row, and all departments that dont have matching row, you could use: Full Outer Join

Comment: aah sorry for misunderstanding. i'm quite new for this php. yes i tried left join. i'm getting all users but instead of department name i'm getting the id of department.  

it is my query $result = "SELECT e.* FROM Users AS e LEFT JOIN `Department` AS u ON e.Dpt_id = u.Dptname"; 
$output = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

Comment: <td><?php echo $single['Dpt_id']; ?></td>.. this is how i'm fetching from while loop

Comment: on Select specify ex. Select u.*, d.department_column_name

Comment: i'm sorry instead of commenting can you please write the answer